# CSVファイル内の時系列データを1秒区切りで平均化するコードを書いているのですがエラーの解消方法を知りたいです

Tags: python, python3, pandas

**前提**
各列にTIME(データ取得日時)、測定値が格納されたCSVファイルを読み込んで、1秒毎に平均化してCSVファイルに出力したいです。
コードを書いてみたのですがエラーが出てしまい対処方法が分からないので教えて頂けるとありがたいです。

下記は使用するCSVデータで名称は「test.csv」です。

```
[LOGGING],RD81DL96_1,2,3,4
DATETIME[YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss.s],INDEX,BIT[1;0],BIT[1;0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],SHORT[DEC.0],TRIGGER[*;-]
TIME
2022/10/20 10:46:13.8,1987,1,0,0,0,0,29,13,22,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,4,2,1,4,4,2,77,5,1,12,4,42,4,0,0,3,5,11,6,6,1,8,89,3,5,7,11,34,8,0,0,253,305,340,378,380,384,427,309,298,301,291,295,283,292,293,298,407,574,418,294,203,122,161,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,236,453,3,332,246,613,772,854,817,922,945,853,957,685,344,253,18,239,468,468,490,467,46,644,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,103,29,113,50,88,157,108,103,63,69,96,88,68,72,104,104,92,50,85,80,55,96,48,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,63,97,196,78,112,55,74,123,128,90,96,78,222,185,76,54,90,39,51,36,57,52,49,39,192,116,18,24,62,8,25,73,76,131,89,122,116,118,28,9,12,77,58,50,4,124,79,129,
2022/10/20 10:46:13.9,1988,1,0,0,0,0,7,13,22,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,5,1,1,3,3,1,408,4,3,12,4,43,3,0,0,3,5,11,8,6,2,7,46,1,4,5,11,34,7,0,0,255,307,341,376,378,384,443,310,310,294,299,294,279,283,289,285,414,553,558,300,235,101,134,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,272,467,21,332,319,536,755,845,788,804,868,900,908,760,333,257,6,240,426,429,500,467,47,666,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,106,38,114,52,91,152,113,111,64,56,108,82,30,87,94,74,57,61,97,75,61,85,58,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,72,62,212,90,81,47,69,100,88,97,89,75,188,155,51,20,98,52,56,33,44,53,52,55,198,119,96,26,59,16,26,19,123,143,110,114,109,149,90,9,10,70,56,0,165,111,109,133,
2022/10/20 10:46:14.0,1989,1,0,0,0,0,3,12,22,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,5,1,2,2,4,1,5,4,1,11,4,43,3,0,0,2,4,12,7,7,2,7,0,2,4,5,11,33,6,0,0,253,305,338,372,376,384,440,339,313,305,299,291,281,300,287,281,363,465,615,337,306,137,133,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,289,398,44,344,310,398,745,835,768,853,916,879,900,802,348,256,8,208,409,448,496,465,42,585,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,89,50,127,35,118,177,138,101,73,71,108,85,62,47,80,127,55,56,95,153,61,198,43,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,82,160,99,40,55,60,80,60,118,104,82,119,128,42,102,78,47,67,32,31,45,45,49,189,124,101,23,60,17,23,12,157,124,104,123,119,140,132,1,9,71,57,9,209,131,91,128,
2022/10/20 10:46:14.1,1990,1,0,0,0,0,4,12,22,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,1,1,3,4,1,7,4,1,13,4,43,3,0,0,1,5,11,7,7,1,7,3,1,4,5,11,35,7,0,0,253,304,335,367,374,384,437,372,313,306,307,298,283,304,281,279,319,370,616,426,363,246,93,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,281,438,31,341,322,262,615,824,737,840,918,925,908,816,369,253,94,127,399,408,536,486,48,452,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,98,51,110,58,104,162,114,89,74,80,94,82,36,77,87,119,1,66,77,90,56,130,66,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,49,94,220,111,63,40,134,101,73,78,129,68,115,131,49,88,99,45,59,34,40,50,59,43,192,128,88,98,53,17,22,69,89,129,122,115,119,133,123,42,11,63,60,71,230,99,114,136,
2022/10/20 10:46:14.2,1991,1,0,0,0,0,1,13,22,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,2,1,3,3,1,7,596,2,10,3,42,2,0,0,3,6,13,7,8,2,8,4,130,4,6,11,32,8,0,0,252,304,334,366,372,383,432,375,333,312,302,289,290,311,286,280,301,358,519,434,298,346,152,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,277,431,44,368,314,243,481,817,711,877,965,913,905,827,424,282,90,120,375,399,518,524,55,426,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,98,34,105,50,80,163,104,110,76,78,76,82,59,65,76,106,39,55,81,121,55,84,51,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,74,212,82,83,60,90,33,92,88,135,59,85,113,42,100,92,58,65,36,47,46,56,40,209,125,101,116,51,20,23,26,58,93,129,127,118,138,124,113,12,59,58,79,120,84,103,137,
```

**実現したいこと**
・上記CSVデータを1秒刻みで平均化したい
2022/10/20 10:46:13台は46:13.8から46:13.9の2行のデータで平均化
2022/10/20 10:46:14台は46:14.0から46:14.2の3行のデータで平均化
その1秒の中で持っているデータの行数が異なっていても、持っている個数に応じて平均化したい
実際に使用するデータは上記のようなデータが無数に格納されるので、今回の46:13台、46:14台だけが持っている個数で平均化できれば良いわけでは無い

・平均化されたデータを再度CSVファイルに出力したい

**ソースコード**

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.read_csv("test.csv",encoding="cp932",sep=',',index_col=0,parse_dates=True,skiprows=2)

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME']) # 日時情報が入った列をdatetime型へ変換

df.set_index('datetime',inplace=True) #indexにdatetime列を指定し、置き換え

df_resample = df.resample('S').sum()

df_resample.to_csv('output.comcsv')
```

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'TIME'

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/ehawfg83rj4ltf) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: マルチポスト先で解決したようですね。

Comment: すみません。他サイトで解決しましたが連絡が遅れました。次回から他サイトで質問した場合は明示するようにいたします。

Answer (score 0):

csvの`TIME`列がインデックスとして指定されているので、`df['TIME']`の形式でカラムとして取得できません。
`df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])`を`df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`と書き換えることで正しく動作します。

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。インデックス列に指定されているとdfで認識されないことを初めて知りました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

もう一つの方法として`pd.read_csv(...)`する際に`index_col=0`を指定しないことでも動作するでしょう。
この行を：

```
df =pd.read_csv("test.csv",encoding="cp932",sep=',',index_col=0,parse_dates=True,skiprows=2)
```

こちらに変更することで出来ます。

```
df =pd.read_csv("test.csv",encoding="cp932",sep=',',parse_dates=True,skiprows=2)
```

それから最後のファイル出力には`encoding="cp932"`が指定されていないようですが、UTF-8で出力されても大丈夫ですか？
あと拡張子も`.comcsv`となっていますがtypoですかね。

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございました。indexを最初に指定しないことでも対応可能とのこと教えて頂きありがとうございました。ファイル出力もcp932必要でした。.comcsvはcsvの間違いでした。

Answer (score 0):

平均化したいとのことですのでsumではなくmeanにしました。

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.read_csv("test.csv",encoding="cp932",sep=',',index_col=0,parse_dates=True,skiprows=2)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df_resample = df.resample('S').mean()
df_resample.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございました。平均化ではmeanなのにミスしていました。教えて頂きありがとうございました。